# How to render a plugin added dynamically?

Tags: jquery, facebook

This is my [code](http://jsfiddle.net/pkeAb/) :

## HTML

```
<div id="fb-root"></div><script>window.fbAsyncInit = function() { FB.init({ appId: '1234', channelUrl: 'http://www.mywebsite.com/support/channel.html', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true }); }; (function(d) { var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; if (d.getElementById(id)) { return; } js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true; js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"; ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref); } (document)); </script>

<fb:like href="http://www.google.com" send="false" layout="button_count" width="auto" show_faces="true" font=""></fb:like>

<div style="padding-top:30px;">
    <a id="addNewLink" href="javascript:void(0);">Add New Facebook's "I Like"</a>
</div>

<div style="padding-top:30px;" id="newFBContent"></div>
```

## jQuery

```
$('#addNewLink').click(function () {
    $('#newFBContent').html('<fb:like href="http://www.facebook.com" send="false" layout="button_count" width="auto" show_faces="true" font=""></fb:like>')
});
```

on page loading, I render an "I Like Plugin". Than, clicking on the link, I add a new one, and I'd also like render it! In fact, if I add again the .js library, it crash (obviously).

So, how can I render it?

Please note : I want to avoid iFrame!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook tags dont render when generated dynamically using Jquery](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/3305658/facebook-tags-dont-render-when-generated-dynamically-using-jquery)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do the job:

```
FB.XFBML.parse( document.getElementById("newFBContent"), function() {
    //plugin rendered
});
```

You should call FB.XFBML.parse after you've added the new content to the DOM.

Comment: It's a bit sad that timestamp of an answers wasn't considered. ;)

Comment: @markzzz, you really can't know who is the downvoter (and if he even one of those answered the question). Let's hope he will show up and describe the reason (as for me it's just a dup, but that what close votes are for). ;)

Answer (score 3):

You missed one line, try:

```
$('#addNewLink').click(function () {
    $('#newFBContent').html('<fb:like href="http://www.facebook.com" send="false" layout="button_count" width="auto" show_faces="true" font="" ></fb:like>')
//and parse
        FB.XFBML.parse(document.getElementById('newFBContent'));

});
```

Answer (score 3):

Just call to [`FB.XFBML.parse`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.XFBML.parse/) after adding `XFBML` elements to page.

You can also specify root node in which the `XFMBL` tags will be parsed.